# Python code not following line of execution

Tags: python, syntax, runtime-error

*Ignore the parameters and functions names.
I have tested all the functions and they are individually fine.*

In the following code even after **success** has been printed the code in the 
***#non-mutating section*** of the else part is being executed.

Also despite having errors the loop is not terminating.

```
def move(ar,x,y,xi,yi): #move(array,x,y,x-increment,y-increment)

    print(x,y,xi,yi)
    global flag


    while flag != 1:

        if x>=xsize or x<0 or y >=ysize or y<0:  
            function2(ar,x-xi,y-yi,xi,yi,eq)
        try:
            if (ar[y][x] == 1) and (function1(ar,x,y,xi,yi) == 1):
                flag = 1   
            else:
                #non-mutating code
        except Exception as e:
            return

    print("success")
```

Comment: How do you make sure that those lines in `else:` are getting executed? Do you have any other place where you have printed `"success"`?

Comment: Do you call this `move` once or multiple times in your code? Maybe you are seeing the `success` of the previous call.

Comment: With the info provided, we will not be able to help you as from a pure programming point of you what you observed is ridiculous. One way you can identify what's really happening is by debugging. Have you made some try on that?

Comment: @Austin I have not used "success" anywhere else but previously I tried using **break** instead of a flag but the program still did not terminate.